# Allow user to add email accounts to office365 without rights to remove users

Tags: office365

I saw this site with available roles to set:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/add-users/about-admin-roles?view=o365-worldwide

However I would like 'License administrator' but without the possibility to remove users. The reason I want this is to let a customer create its own email accounts for their domain.

If it is possible how can I do it or if not, can you lead me in the right direction? I do have a business account.

Best Regards Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to fulfill your needs.

However, the account becomes not enabled after it is deleted.

You could restore your account within approximately 30 days of deletion.

To restore users in Office 365, see this link:
[Restore a user in Office 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/add-users/restore-user?view=o365-worldwide)